# What happens when I submit my blog on ping sites like pingomatic.com?

Tags: blog, ping-o-matic

After reading "what I should do after posting a blog" I submitted my blog URL in **pingomatic.com**.

Then I got "Pinging complete!" message which shows results as can be seen below. It say "Bookmark this page and come back to it later to automatically re-ping.". I don't actually understand how this works and what happens by this pinging process! Any explanations on how this webapp works?

> Weblogs.com   ***Ping sent.***
>
> Blo.gs            ***Ping sent.***
>
> Feed Burner   ***Ping sent.***
>
> My Yahoo! ***Ping sent.***
>
> ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pingomatic is a service which alerts (pings) multiple RSS aggregators/search engines in one action when there is a new post on your blog. This saves you from having to register your blog to all of the services individually.

From the [Ping-O-Matic main page](http://pingomatic.com/):

> What is this?
>
> Ping-O-Matic is a service to update different search engines that your blog has updated.